# How to convert date in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From 2018-12-14 to 2018/12/14???
I usually miss one day when i send date(datepicker(momentjs))

```
startDate: moment().toDate(), // how to format('YYYY/MM/DD')???
```

Comment: Please spend some time framing the question properly so that the community will find it easy to help you out. I am not talking about english, I am talking about the framing.

Comment: Please refer the  moment [doc](https://momentjs.com/) `moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD')`

Answer (score 4):

```
moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD"); // if you want to convert current date
moment(startDate).format("YYYY/MM/DD"); // if you want to convert given date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
startDate = "2018-12-14";
momentDate = moment(startDate ,'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

If you know the exact format you can put it here.

Answer (score 0):

**For doing with moment you need to use format("YYYY/MM/DD")** [moment](https://momentjs.com/)

**In case you want to do it manually**

If you just want to change `-` to `/` than you can do it like this.

```js
let str =  "2018-12-14";
let op = str.replace(/-/g,'/');
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace `-` to `/` if you have it already formatted but from the example, you gave us it appears that you don't know how to format date at all. So if you really want to do it with `moment` you've got 2 approaches.

1. If you already have formatted startDate and want to reformat it

```js
const reformattedStartDate = moment(startDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```

2. If you are creating new startDate with proper format

```js
const startDate = moment().format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Comment: i already have startDate like this.state and i have 
endDate: null 
<DatePicker label="Дата заверш."
                minDate={startDate}
                value={endDate}
                dateFormat="DD.MM.YYYY"
                onDateChange={this.onChangeEndDate}/>

Comment: @Alexiostigrahauda your link is not working. Please add it to [JSFiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net) at least. Also if you already have startDate and endDate - just format them `moment(startDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD')` but also you can try changing `dateFormat="DD.MM.YYYY"` to `dateFormat="YYYY/MM/DD"` and check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import moment from 'moment';

let date = 2018-12-14;

let resultDate=moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```

Result:

resultDate: 2018/12/14

Answer (score 0):

Use format:

Data: "createdAt": "2022-04-04T18:56:36Z",

```
import { format } from "date-fns";

{format(new Date(reserve.createdAt), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}
```

Result:

04/04/2022 18:56:36

Just be careful with MM and mm, MM is for month and mm is for minute